# Python fill polygon

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, mayavi.mlab

Is there any Python function (matplotlib or mayavi) that can execute the same task as "fill" in Matlab? What I need is, given a polygon defined by a set of points x, y and a color vector c for each point, `fill(x, y, c)` would plot the polygon defined by (x, y) with a color in c[i] for each (x[i], y[i]).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`matplotlib` does it less straight forward than `matlab`, you need to add `polygon` to the axes.

```
from matplotlib.patches import Polygon

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
N = 5
polygon = Polygon(np.random.rand(N, 2), True, facecolor='r')
ax.add_patch(polygon)
```

Note: `facecolor` controls the color of the polygon, and accept string, RGBA or html color code as value.

[image]

if you have a set of Polygon and each of them need to be of a different color you can use the pathcollection:

```
from matplotlib.patches import Polygon
from matplotlib.collections import PatchCollection

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
N = 5
val = np.random.rand(N, 2, 3)
patches = [Polygon(val[:, :, i], True) for i in range(val.shape[-1])]
p = PatchCollection(patches, alpha=0.4)
p.set_array(np.random.rand(3))  # assign colors
ax.add_collection(p)
fig.colorbar(p)
```

[image]

Comment: Well, that‘ not what I need. What I actually need is to attribute a different color to each of the polygon vertices, so the resulting image is the interpolated field.

Comment: In that case try Pathcollection see edit.